# Seaborn OS X : seaborn.pairplot() ValueError: 'transform' must be an instance of 'matplotlib.transform.Transform'

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The following steps were taken inside of jupyter notebook in an attempt to make `seaborn.pairplot()` work. An error from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/matplotlib/transforms.pyc` stopped the function from working.

Below are the python library versions:

```
print(matplotlib.__version__, sns.__version__)

('1.5.1', '0.7.1')
```

A csv of the iris dataset was read

```
data = pandas.read_csv('iris.csv')
data_no_nans = data.dropna()
sns.pairplot(data_no_nans)
```

Error Message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-001343d0343b> in <module>()
----> 1 sns.pairplot(data)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/linearmodels.pyc in pairplot(data, hue, hue_order, palette, vars, x_vars, y_vars, kind, diag_kind, markers, size, aspect, dropna, plot_kws, diag_kws, grid_kws)
   1588                     hue_order=hue_order, palette=palette,
   1589                     diag_sharey=diag_sharey,
-> 1590                     size=size, aspect=aspect, dropna=dropna, **grid_kws)
   1591 
   1592     # Add the markers here as PairGrid has figured out how many levels of the

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.pyc in __init__(self, data, hue, hue_order, palette, hue_kws, vars, x_vars, y_vars, diag_sharey, size, aspect, despine, dropna)
   1253         if despine:
   1254             utils.despine(fig=fig)
-> 1255         fig.tight_layout()
   1256 
   1257     def map(self, func, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in tight_layout(self, renderer, pad, h_pad, w_pad, rect)
   1752                                          renderer,
   1753                                          pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad,
-> 1754                                          rect=rect)
   1755 
   1756         self.subplots_adjust(**kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.pyc in get_tight_layout_figure(fig, axes_list, subplotspec_list, renderer, pad, h_pad, w_pad, rect)
    347                                      subplot_list=subplot_list,
    348                                      ax_bbox_list=ax_bbox_list,
--> 349                                      pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad)
    350 
    351     if rect is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.pyc in auto_adjust_subplotpars(fig, renderer, nrows_ncols, num1num2_list, subplot_list, ax_bbox_list, pad, h_pad, w_pad, rect)
    126         tight_bbox_raw = union([ax.get_tightbbox(renderer) for ax in subplots])
    127         tight_bbox = TransformedBbox(tight_bbox_raw,
--> 128                                      fig.transFigure.inverted())
    129 
    130         row1, col1 = divmod(num1, cols)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/matplotlib/transforms.pyc in __init__(self, bbox, transform, **kwargs)
   1080             msg = ("'transform' must be an instance of"
   1081                    " 'matplotlib.transform.Transform'")
-> 1082             raise ValueError(msg)
   1083         if transform.input_dims != 2 or transform.output_dims != 2:
   1084             msg = "The input and output dimensions of 'transform' must be 2"

ValueError: 'transform' must be an instance of 'matplotlib.transform.Transform'
```

Regplot works perfectly

```
sns.regplot(x="petal_length", y="petal_width", data=data)
```

**EDIT**

I suspect it has to do with matplotlib's font manager malfunctioning. I deleted fontconfig and spicy directories from ~/.cache/ and got a new error message: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Locked'

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-001343d0343b> in <module>()
----> 1 sns.pairplot(data)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/linearmodels.pyc in pairplot(data, hue, hue_order, palette, vars, x_vars, y_vars, kind, diag_kind, markers, size, aspect, dropna, plot_kws, diag_kws, grid_kws)
   1588                     hue_order=hue_order, palette=palette,
   1589                     diag_sharey=diag_sharey,
-> 1590                     size=size, aspect=aspect, dropna=dropna, **grid_kws)
   1591 
   1592     # Add the markers here as PairGrid has figured out how many levels of the

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.pyc in __init__(self, data, hue, hue_order, palette, hue_kws, vars, x_vars, y_vars, diag_sharey, size, aspect, despine, dropna)
   1253         if despine:
   1254             utils.despine(fig=fig)
-> 1255         fig.tight_layout()
   1256 
   1257     def map(self, func, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in tight_layout(self, renderer, pad, h_pad, w_pad, rect)
   1737         """
   1738 
-> 1739         from .tight_layout import (get_renderer, get_tight_layout_figure,
   1740                                    get_subplotspec_list)
   1741 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py in <module>()
     15 from matplotlib.transforms import TransformedBbox, Bbox
     16 
---> 17 from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
     18 rcParams = matplotlib.rcParams
     19 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/matplotlib/font_manager.py in <module>()
   1448                 verbose.report("Using fontManager instance from %s" % _fmcache)
   1449         except:
-> 1450             _rebuild()
   1451     else:
   1452         _rebuild()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/matplotlib/font_manager.py in _rebuild()
   1433 
   1434         if _fmcache:
-> 1435             with cbook.Locked(cachedir):
   1436                 json_dump(fontManager, _fmcache)
   1437 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Locked'
```

Comment: works for me with the same versions.

Comment: I guess its worth mentioning that its a home-brew matplotlib and pip seaborn install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am answering my own question now.

I solved the problem by using a Macports virtual environment

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install python27
sudo port install py27-virtualenv


/opt/local/bin/virtualenv-2.7 $HOME/local/python/27
```

Add to .bash_profile:

```
alias py27="source $HOME/local/python/27/bin/activate"
```

Run in terminal to set virtual env and install required packages with pip.

```
py27
which pip
   $HOME/local/python/27/bin/pip
pip install ipython etc
```

It is strange that the home-brew installation bugged out, and I am wondering if there were any conflicting packages installed.

Not sure if its related, but here is my .bash_profile:

```
# some settings to prefer homebrew paths in case it exists:
if which -s brew ; then
    PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

This could of been messing things up.

Comment: I do not have those homebrew switches: but I do get the same errors. There is something amiss in `brew matplotlib`